Bulk update with conditional logic when updating column
How can I convert this SELECT query into an update query that actually works, for some reason when I try and assign values to my variables the SELECT statement doesn't even work.
UserlabelId UUID;
UserlabelId2 UUID;
UserlabelId3 UUID;

SELECT INTO UserlabelId  id from labels where name = 'label1';
SELECT INTO UserlabelId2 id from labels where name = 'label2';
SELECT INTO UserlabelId3 id from labels where name = 'label3';

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (u.role_id == UserLabelId)  THEN 'L1'    
    WHEN (u.role_id == UserLabelId2)  THEN 'L2'    
    ELSE 'L3'
  END AS new_user_label
FROM transactions t
   INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = t.sold_by_user_id


BTW: Where did you find that syntax, and why do you not share the errors that you should have when trying to execute this?

@Luuk the syntax error is just 'syntax error at or near "UserLabelId" on line#1

That is not going to work outside of function/procedure. Look at DO if you want a one shot anonymous function or plpgsql for a permanent function.

Looks like you only need an UPDATE statement, that uses in that same statement some data from other tables. Use the UPDATE ... FROM ... syntax. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html for details.

UserlabelId UUID; is not valid SQL, that can only result in an error message.

To be able to use variables you have to utilize anonymous blocks or create a stored procedure or function.
An example of an anonymous block similar to your needs:
do $$
declare
    UserlabelId UUID;
    UserlabelId2 UUID;
    UserlabelId3 UUID;
    rows_affected int;     
begin
    select gen_random_uuid() into UserlabelId;
    select gen_random_uuid() into UserlabelId2;
    select gen_random_uuid() into UserlabelId3;

    raise notice 'UserlabelId: %', UserlabelId;
    raise notice 'UserlabelId2: %', UserlabelId2;
    raise notice 'UserlabelId3: %', UserlabelId3;

    update test set user_uuid=UserlabelId
    where user_uuid is not null and first_name='John';
    get diagnostics rows_affected = row_count;
    raise notice 'Rows updated: %', rows_affected;


    exception 
        when others then
            raise notice 'The following error occurred: %.', 

sqlerrm;    
    end $$;

The output:
UserlabelId: df618f55-755e-498e-ba95-4d5d85024c52
UserlabelId2: a43d9348-7d8b-46f3-9e2a-9a557563865c
UserlabelId3: e995fde3-65d3-4409-8c33-6e73b867c5c5
Rows updated: 1

